# SQL Query result, comparison and where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a site and i need to retrieve some information. I have this query.

```
$SQL = "SELECT distretto_108, provinca_113, regioni_116, tipologia_pdv_106, 
        richiesta_ccnl_107, coop_va_109, nome_pdv_110, 
        indirizzo_pdv_111, localita_112 
        FROM civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22 ";
```

I need to add this other code:

```
WHERE civicrm_event.title_en_US='".addslashes($_GET["titles"])."'
```

but it's not working...
i need to compare let's say the id of another table with the id of the current table... How to do that?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hello **SQL injection**!

Comment: Oh no no, i am trying to add some tables together... i have to create a report for events...

Comment: 1. use mysql_real_escape_string() or PDO with paramater bindings not addslashes()  2. What is the problem?  Why can't you add the where clause?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would if i were an expert :)
let me explain... i get an information from a get method and i need to join two tables but i don't know how to use the comparison... example, civicrm_event.id=civicrm_contact.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn something about joining tables...

Do not know what the relation is between the two tables (simply said: what column from one table is pointing to what column at other one), but try something similar (modification needed to meet You DB structure) - now lets assume both tables have related column called event_id:

```
$SQL = "SELECT distretto_108, provinca_113, regioni_116, tipologia_pdv_106, 
        richiesta_ccnl_107, coop_va_109, nome_pdv_110, 
        indirizzo_pdv_111, localita_112 
    FROM civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22 cvistlsp22
    LEFT JOIN civicrm_event ce ON ce.event_id = cvistlsp22.event_id
    WHERE ce.title_en_US='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["titles"])."'";
```

`civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22` table name is very long and You will not be able to create a table with such long name in other DBMS (e.g. ORACLE), so try to make it shorter while still self-describing...

If You want to join tables they have to have a relation, read more about relations and how to use them here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving the data from table civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22 in your query while the where clause you are adding, refers to the table civicrm_event. You need to add this new table in the from clause and do a join among the two tables using some common key. Example below:

```
$SQL = "
SELECT distretto_108, provinca_113, regioni_116, tipologia_pdv_106, richiesta_ccnl_107, coop_va_109, nome_pdv_110, indirizzo_pdv_111, localita_112 
FROM civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22 
  JOIN civicrm_event ON civicrm_value_informazioni_su_tute_le_schede_p_22.ID_PK = civicrm_event.ID_FK
WHERE civicrm_event.title_en_US='".addslashes($_GET["titles"])
";
```

You need to replace the ID_PK and ID_FK with the relevant Primary and Foreign Keys that bind the tables together.

Please note using query params like that is not recommended. Please read [PHP Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for more explanation.